# Numpy array indexing with two dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have one numpy array with two dimensions, for the example let's say :

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,6,5,8,9]])
```

I tried to do `a = a[a[0]>2]` but i got an error. I would like to obtain:

```
 array([[3, 4, 5],
   [5, 8, 9]])
```

Is it possible ? thanks !

Comment: .. `a[:,a[0]>2]`?

Comment: well, it was simple thanks ! could you just explain why `a[a[0]>2]` doesn't work ?

Comment: See if this helps - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Yes i saw it before but it's not very clear and the part with `b[:,5]` is not exactly the same case as me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the options step by step:

```
In [75]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,6,5,8,9]])
```

first row, a 1d array

```
In [76]: a[0]                     
Out[76]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

where that first row is >2, a 1d boolean array of same size

```
In [77]: a[0]>2
Out[77]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Using that direct, produces an error:

```
In [78]: a[a[0]>2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-631a57b67cdb> in <module>()
----> 1 a[a[0]>2]

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5
```

First dimension of `a` is 2, but the boolean index (mask) has size 2 (2nd dim)

So we need to apply it to the 2nd dimension.  2d indexing syntax: `x[i, j]`, `x[:, j]` to select all rows, but subset of columns:

```
In [79]: a[:,a[0]>2]
Out[79]: 
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [5, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: I was re-reading this answer, did you mean `but the boolean index (mask) has size 5 (2nd dim)` instead of `size 2` ?